# Bootstrap Navbar unable to collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would want to click the button in the header to expand the list of links, but it only expands, and unable to hide. What should I do to get it working normally?

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">

        <!-- This is where the button to collapse the list is -->
        <a href="#HomePage"><img class="icon" alt="Brand" src="img/icon.ico"></a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseBtn" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseBtn">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- This is the list I expect to collapse when I hit the button -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse in" id="collapseBtn">
        <ul class="container-fluid nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li><a href="#edu"><h4 class="navbar-items">Education</h4></a></li>
          <li><a href="#exp"><h4 class="navbar-items">Experience</h4></a></li>
          <li><a href="#skill"><h4 class="navbar-items">Skills</h4></a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact"><h4 class="navbar-items">Contact Me</h4></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: can you show us the full code? you did not forget to include the `bootstrap` files right? I copied you code and works fine for me. The initial collapse does not work though.

Comment: Just remove the `in` class from `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse in" id="collapseBtn">`, like so `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseBtn">`, That should be it.

Comment: @DavidDomain I've tried that, but when I clicked on the button it doesn't expand, which is really weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the class of `in` in your navbar-collapse causing it to remain open other than that your Code is working fine as you can see in the following fiddle

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/LLu43qh6/)

You will want to remove the class of `in`  From your `navbar-collapse` and then if you are having trouble getting it to open you more than likely forgot to load jquery.js before loading bootstrap.js.  So before your bootstrap javascript file you need to load the jquery javascript library.  Bootstrap's javascript works off of jquery so you need to load the jquery library first.  So before the bootstrap js script link add this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then after that load your bootstrap js file

```
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've done what you've said, but then I find this: "Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo='. The resource has been blocked." Would it matter?

Comment: Actually fixed it, it is your answer + the issue above I mentioned, thanks though.